# Why does indexPathForItemAtPoint always return nil

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, flowlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` contained in an `UIViewController` that uses a horizontal `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. I'm also using a prototype cell created in my `UIStoryboard`. I want to create a custom paging, so I'm using `- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset`.

The problem is that every time I'm trying to get the `indexPath` corresponding to the targetContentOffset (the point in the scroll view where the scroll will stop), the collection view returns nil even though the point is clearly inside the collection view contentSize.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:(*targetContentOffset)];
    // Do something with indexPath    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using the ivar? Check whether or not `_collectionView` itself is nil first.

Comment: I've tried to use the scrollView variable itself but the result is the same. I'm positive both are not nil when I call the method.

Answer (score 0):

The collectionView does not know the indexPath for the targetContentOffset yet.

You have to ask the collectionViewLayout to give you the attribute of the item which will be layout at this position.

Try something like this:

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute = [_collectionView.collectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect){(*targetContentOffset).x, 0, 10, self.collectionView.bounds.size.height}][0];
```